# How to dump autoload in custom installer plugin

Tags: php, installation, composer-php, autoload

I have been trying to write a custom installer for my composer package. But can't get it to work.
What I need and How I'm doing it now:

- I need my package to be installed on root directory. My package name is rootdata21/hati, so I moved the hati folder there on the project root folder.
- Now I updated the composer.json by addeding an entry to autoload psr4 properties such as:

  {
  "autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
  "hati\": "hati/"
  }
  }
  }

But I actually don't know how I can get the composer to re dump autoloader to reflect this new autload entry in composer.json file. Here is my Installer class.

```
<?php

namespace hati\installer;

use Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller;
use Composer\IO\IOInterface;
use Composer\Package\PackageInterface;
use Composer\PartialComposer;
use Composer\Repository\InstalledRepositoryInterface;
use Composer\Script\ScriptEvents;
use hati\config\ConfigWriter;
use React\Promise\PromiseInterface;

class Installer extends LibraryInstaller {

    private string $root;
    private string $hatiDir;
    protected $composer;

    public function __construct(IOInterface $io, PartialComposer $composer, $root) {
        $this -> composer = $composer;
        $this -> root = $root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $this -> hatiDir = $root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'hati' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

        parent::__construct($io, $composer);
    }

    public function getInstallPath(PackageInterface $package): string {
        return 'rootdata21';
    }

    public function install(InstalledRepositoryInterface $repo, PackageInterface $package): ?PromiseInterface {

        if (file_exists($this -> hatiDir)) {
            $choice = $this -> io -> ask('Existing hati folder found. Do you want to delete it? [y/n]: ', 'n');
            if ($choice === 'y') {
                self::rmdir($this -> hatiDir);
            } else {
                $this -> io -> critical('Hati installation has been cancelled. Please delete hati folder manually.');
                return null;
            }
        }

        return parent::install($repo, $package)->then(function () {

            // Move hati folder to project root directory
            $old = $this -> root . 'rootdata21'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'hati';
            rename($old, $this -> hatiDir);

            // delete the rootdata21 folder
            self::rmdir($this -> root . 'rootdata21');

            // generate/update the hati.json file on the project root directory
            $createNewConfig = true;
            if (file_exists($this -> root . 'hati.json')) {

                while(true) {
                    $ans = $this -> io -> ask('Existing hati.json found. Do you want to merge it with new config? [y/n]: ');
                    if ($ans !== 'y' && $ans !== 'n') continue;
                    break;
                }
                $createNewConfig = $ans == 'n';
            }

            require_once "{$this -> hatiDir}config" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "ConfigWriter.php";
            $result = ConfigWriter::write($this->root, $createNewConfig);

            // show the result to the user
            if ($result['success']) {
                $this -> io -> info($result['msg']);

                $welcomeFile = $this -> hatiDir . 'page/welcome.txt';
                if (file_exists($welcomeFile)) include($welcomeFile);

            } else {
                $this -> io -> error($result['msg']);
            }

            $this -> dumpAutoload();
        });
    }

    public function update(InstalledRepositoryInterface $repo, PackageInterface $initial, PackageInterface $target) {
        return parent::update($repo, $initial, $target) -> then(function () {
            require_once "{$this -> hatiDir}config" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "ConfigWriter.php";
            $result = ConfigWriter::write($this->root);

            // show the result to the user
            if ($result['success']) {
                $this -> io -> info('Hati has been updated successfully');
            } else {
                $this -> io -> error($result['msg']);
            }
        });
    }

    public function supports($packageType): bool {
        return 'hati-installer' === $packageType;
    }

    private function dumpAutoload(): void {
        $composerJsonPath = $this -> root . 'composer.json';
        $composerJson = json_decode(file_get_contents($composerJsonPath), true);
        $composerJson['autoload']['psr-4']['hati\\'] = 'hati/';
        file_put_contents($composerJsonPath, json_encode($composerJson, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));

        // Regenerate the Composer autoload files to include your classes
        $this -> composer -> getEventDispatcher() -> dispatchScript(ScriptEvents::POST_AUTOLOAD_DUMP);
    }

    public static function rmdir($dir): bool {
        if (!file_exists($dir)) return true;

        if (!is_dir($dir)) return unlink($dir);

        foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
            if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') continue;

            if (!self::rmdir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item)) return false;
        }

        return rmdir($dir);
    }

}
```

Comment: From top of my head you can't (there is an extra-cyclying refreshing autoloading before/after plugin installs), but in any case I'd strongly advice not to modify the root composer.json via a plugin during install. Why don't you just add the psr-4 rule to the autoloader instance? Where does the requirement stem from having autoload for the files you copy into the root? Or from where at all to copy files into the root folder? As composer would already have the package files under autoload, there is normally only a requirement for data-files to be at different places.

Comment: It is important for the packages that all its file are placed on the project root folder. I have updated my code. Please check.

Comment: Well, not saying you can't have your reasons, that was just some food of thought. It may help to double-check preconditions if they are really required (and then to look for what). You've already learned that the approach with the autoloader is not feasible. For the recursive directory removal I'd suggest you make use of the routines that are available with composer itself. And create a test-suite for your plugin that runs it against all composer versions and php versions there are (as good as you're able to), to identify which version combinations you want to support with the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to achieve what I wanted to do. So here, I will explain what help I asked for.

Normally without using any custom installer plugin, composer installs my package in the vendor directory under folder "**rootdata21/hati**". But for some reasons, my entire package source code needs to be on project root directory. And I also don't want that rootdata21 as parent folder.

So I wrote a plugin for it. The plugin returns "**rootdata21**" as installation path. It gets my package on root directory but the folder structure is now "rootdata21/hati". So I had to override the **install** method to modify that. However, even when I get my desired folder location and structure by copying/renaming/deleting folder from "rootdata21/hati" to "hati", the autoloader doesn't work for my relocated source code. I then have to manually update the composer.json file to dump the autoloader which defeats the purpose of having the installer. And this is what I was trying to achieve, so that after moving my package folder to project root, the autoloader should still work.

Here is my final updated installer code which works they way I want.

```php
public function getInstallPath(PackageInterface $package): string { return 'hati'; }
```

```php
public function install(InstalledRepositoryInterface $repo, PackageInterface $package): ?PromiseInterface {

    // Setting custom psr-4 entry for hati folder being on project root
    $autoload = $package -> getAutoload();
    if (isset($autoload['psr-4'])) {
        $customPSR4 = ['hati\\' => '/',];
        $autoload['psr-4'] = array_merge($autoload['psr-4'], $customPSR4);

        // Let the composer know about this
        $package -> setAutoload($autoload);
    }

    return parent::install($repo, $package) -> then(function () {

        // Manipulate the hati/hati folder to hati on project root
        self::copy($this -> root . 'hati' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'hati', $this -> root . '_temp');
        self::rmdir($this -> root . 'hati');
        rename($this -> root . '_temp',$this -> root . 'hati');

        // rest of the installation code goes here...
    });
}
```

After all of these, **vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php** sets classpath correctly as you can see in the screenshot.
[image: 2023-07-31_211426]

I had to return "hati" as installation path, because returning "rootdata21" and the installation code above gets me the following as autoload_psr4.php record which doesn't work.

```php
'hati\\' => array($baseDir . '/rootdata')
```